# Strange syntax and error when executing lambda function with multiple arguments

Tags: python, lambda

I'm using this tutorial to learn about lambda functions:

[How to Use Python lambda Functions](https://realpython.com/python-lambda/)

There is an example involving this line:

```
full_name = lambda first, last: f'Full name: {first.title()} {last.title()}'
```

I have 2 questions:

1. There is an "f" in front of "Full name".  What does this "f" do?
2. When I run this line, I immediately get this error:

   ```
   File "<stdin>", line 1
       full_name = lambda first, last: f'Full name: {first.title()} {last.title()}'
                                                                                  ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
   ```

Why does this happen?  Why did the tutorial show a properly executed function, but I get an error?

Comment: "f-strings" are explained in the [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) section of the online documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So firstly this `f` is a new, elegant way to format a string with variables. I invite you to read https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/ that tells the whole story.

However, this exists only since Python 3.6. Can you confirm your version?

```
python --version
```

Kind regards -

Comment: That's the problem - I have version 2.7.15.  I'll get an updated version.  Thanks!